# Inserting markdown from the web into Quarto document

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, quarto

I'm sure this should be straightforward - but how should I go about getting markdown from a URL and inserting it into a .qmd document, as if I'd copied and pasted it?

For example, if I wanted to grab the example document from https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rt2zz/e0a1d6ab2682d2c47746950b84c0b6ee/raw/83b8b4814c3417111b9b9bef86a552608506603e/markdown-sample.md and drop it into a qmd document, to later output to pdf, how should I go about that?

I've tried the following:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: pdf
editor: visual
---

```{r, results='asis'}
library(httr)
url="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rt2zz/e0a1d6ab2682d2c47746950b84c0b6ee/raw/83b8b4814c3417111b9b9bef86a552608506603e/markdown-sample.md"
response=GET(url)
print(content(response))
````

However, when I try to render the document, I get an error "compilation failed- error
Undefined control sequence....."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `print()` with `cat()`:

````yaml
---
title: "Untitled"
format: pdf
editor: visual
---

```{r, results='asis'}
library(httr)
url="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rt2zz/e0a1d6ab2682d2c47746950b84c0b6ee/raw/83b8b4814c3417111b9b9bef86a552608506603e/markdown-sample.md"
response=GET(url)
cat(content(response))
```
````

Comment: Many thanks - I'd never have got to that myself. ?cat hints at why this works (" cat performs much less conversion than print"), but it's not exactly clear.

Comment: Quarto docs provide few examples for `results: asis` and `output: asis` , I guess this is  why  `print()`  seemed the most likely culprit.  https://quarto.org/docs/computations/execution-options.html#raw-output (make sure to switch from Jupyter to Knitr example) and  https://quarto.org/docs/reference/cells/cells-knitr.html#cell-output . If you set `keep-tex: true`  for pdf output format, you can also compare resulting tex files when using `cat()` and `print()`  . Or switch output format to markdown, with `print()`  the result might be quite surprising.